How to include orcid in my paper
I am using this template https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle.zip on overleaf
I want to include \orcid for each one of the authors
here is the current script
 \author[label1]{fName1 lName1  \orcid{0000-0000-0000-0000}}
 \ead{fname1.lname1@myuni.edu}

 \author[label2]{fName2 lName2  \orcid{0000-0000-0000-0000}}
 \ead{fname2.lname2@myuni.edu}
 
 \author[label1]{fName3 lName3  \orcid{0000-0000-0000-0000}}
 \ead{fname3.lname3@myuni.edu}
 
 \affiliation[label1]{organization={My University},
             addressline={},
             city={},
             postcode={},
             state={},
             country={}}

 \affiliation[label2]{organization={My University},
             addressline={},
             city={},
             postcode={},
             state={},
             country={}}

but i am getting this error

Undefined control sequence.

How can I include orcid without errors?

Look at the orcidlink package; https://www.ctan.org/pkg/orcidlink

If you are preparing an article to submit to a specific journal that uses this template, just follow their instructions. If they do not explicitly support ORCID, I would suggest that you do not add it by yourself.
